# JPA @OrderBy annotation not working with @ManyToMany

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa

I have entity classes `Classroom` and `ApuStudent`. This is my `Classroom` class:

```
@Entity(name = "Classroom")
@Table(name = "classroom")
public class Classroom extends BaseEntity
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6119375402140845721L;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinTable(name = "classroom_student", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "classroom_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    @OrderBy("name")
    private Set<ApuStudent> student = new HashSet<>();
}
```

The annotation `@OrderBy` will throw an exception

```
Unknown column 'student5_.name' in 'order clause'
```

This is my `ApuStudent` class:

```
@Entity(name = "ApuStudent")
@Table(name = "apu_student")
public class ApuStudent extends BaseEntity
{
    @Column(name = "tp", nullable = false, length = 8, unique = true)
    private String tp;
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String name;
}
```

and this is the sql from output:

```
select
    classroom0_.id as id1_6_0_,
    classroom0_.date_created as date_cre2_6_0_,
    classroom0_.date_modified as date_mod3_6_0_,
    classroom0_.admin as admin7_6_0_,
    classroom0_.classroom_id as classroo4_6_0_,
    classroom0_.lecturer as lecturer8_6_0_,
    classroom0_.module as module9_6_0_,
    classroom0_.password as password5_6_0_,
    classroom0_.second_marker as second_10_6_0_,
    classroom0_.status as status6_6_0_,
    apuadmin1_.id as id1_1_1_,
    apuadmin1_.date_created as date_cre2_1_1_,
    apuadmin1_.date_modified as date_mod3_1_1_,
    apuadmin1_.aid as aid4_1_1_,
    apuadmin1_.name as name5_1_1_,
    apulecture2_.id as id1_2_2_,
    apulecture2_.date_created as date_cre2_2_2_,
    apulecture2_.date_modified as date_mod3_2_2_,
    apulecture2_.lid as lid4_2_2_,
    apulecture2_.name as name5_2_2_,
    apumodule3_.id as id1_3_3_,
    apumodule3_.date_created as date_cre2_3_3_,
    apumodule3_.date_modified as date_mod3_3_3_,
    apumodule3_.module_code as module_c4_3_3_,
    apumodule3_.module_title as module_t5_3_3_,
    apulecture4_.id as id1_2_4_,
    apulecture4_.date_created as date_cre2_2_4_,
    apulecture4_.date_modified as date_mod3_2_4_,
    apulecture4_.lid as lid4_2_4_,
    apulecture4_.name as name5_2_4_,
    student5_.classroom_id as classroo1_6_5_,
    apustudent6_.id as student_2_7_5_,
    apustudent6_.id as id1_4_6_,
    apustudent6_.date_created as date_cre2_4_6_,
    apustudent6_.date_modified as date_mod3_4_6_,
    apustudent6_.name as name4_4_6_,
    apustudent6_.tp as tp5_4_6_ 
from
    classroom classroom0_ 
inner join
    apu_admin apuadmin1_ 
        on classroom0_.admin=apuadmin1_.id 
inner join
    apu_lecturer apulecture2_ 
        on classroom0_.lecturer=apulecture2_.id 
inner join
    apu_module apumodule3_ 
        on classroom0_.module=apumodule3_.module_code 
left outer join
    apu_lecturer apulecture4_ 
        on classroom0_.second_marker=apulecture4_.id 
left outer join
    classroom_student student5_ 
        on classroom0_.id=student5_.classroom_id 
left outer join
    apu_student apustudent6_ 
        on student5_.student_id=apustudent6_.id 
where
    classroom0_.id=? 
order by
    student5_.name
```

any idea?

**UPDATE**
I am using MySQL and Spring JPA, and I find out the problem will not happen if I directly select from `Classroom` like `classroomRepo.findAll();`. The problem happens when I select from other entity class. For example, in this case, I was select from `Assignment` class like this: `assignmentRepo.findAll();`. This is my `Assignment` class:

```
@Entity(name = "Assignment")
@Table(name = "assignment")
public class Assignment extends BaseEntity
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8962490607828514209L;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "classroom", nullable = false, referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Classroom classroom;
    //other columns omitted
}
```

If I select directly from classroomRepo, it will have a query like this:

```
select
    student0_.classroom_id as classroo1_6_0_,
    student0_.student_id as student_2_7_0_,
    apustudent1_.id as id1_4_1_,
    apustudent1_.date_created as date_cre2_4_1_,
    apustudent1_.date_modified as date_mod3_4_1_,
    apustudent1_.name as name4_4_1_,
    apustudent1_.tp as tp5_4_1_ 
from
    classroom_student student0_ 
inner join
    apu_student apustudent1_ 
        on student0_.student_id=apustudent1_.id 
where
    student0_.classroom_id=? 
order by
    apustudent1_.name
```

BUT, if I select from assignmentRepo, the query will be different:

```
left outer join
    classroom_student student5_ 
        on classroom0_.id=student5_.classroom_id
```

it didn't select few columns:

```
apustudent1_.id as id1_4_1_,
apustudent1_.date_created as date_cre2_4_1_,
apustudent1_.date_modified as date_mod3_4_1_,
apustudent1_.name as name4_4_1_,
apustudent1_.tp as tp5_4_1_
```

may I know how to solve this?

Comment: Aren't you missing the `student5_.name` in the select statement?

Comment: I am using Spring JPA, I don't enter the query by myself, Spring JPA does it

Comment: Can you tell us if @OrderBy is `org.hibernate.annotations.OrderBy` or `javax.persistence.OrderBy` ?

Comment: Would you provide the mapping to the `Student` entity?

Comment: @pleft it is `javax.persistence`

Comment: What database are you using? Moreover if you copy-paste the generated statement and run it in the database what's the output?

Comment: I have updated my question. @NikolasCharalambidis

Comment: Ok, so post all your entities involved to examine the relations and all your relevant repos. Hiding information won't help you solve your problem. Moreover the SQL output is from the select to the Assignment class? Because I cannot see a relevant to Assignment table

Comment: A hashset cannot be 'ordered'.

Comment: @pleft updated. My repo is just basic interface which extends 
Spring `JpaRepository`

Comment: @DN1 then what can be? As far as I know, it cannot be `List<>`

Comment: Why can it not be a List? You are saying to JPA "sort these elements in this way" and then putting them into a Set and they lose that ordering and are now ordered in the natural Set order. Whether you *need* ordering is a different issue, but if you do set an `@OrderBy` then you need to put the elements into something that preserves it or it is utterly pointless. Clearly this doesnt answer why Hibernate throws exceptions ... it is just that it is WRONG

Comment: Your comments are incorrect @DN1. The JPA provider can use smomething like a `LinkedHashSet`  in this case.

Comment: Not incorrect at all. He instantiates as a HashSet. I said it needs to be instantiated into an implementation that retains his ordering. That does NOT preclude LinkedHashSet, or TreeSet. aka what I said `something that preserves it`.

Comment: It doesn't matter what he instantiates. Hibernate will set the reference to e.g. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/collection/internal/PersistentSortedSet.html